# Android - GridView setSelection not working

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-viewpager, selection

Currently using a tabbar/viewpager with fragments setup for this project. Fragment 2 contains a gridview. At app startup I'm trying to select a gridview cell by default - but no matter what I do it does not 'select'. I'm beginning to wonder if this is because at the time the selection tries to take place, the gridview is off screen (page/fragment 2 of the viewpager).

What I'm doing is after the getView method of the GridViewAdapter is initially complete (I'm comparing position to total number of possible cells to determine this) I fire a listener message to select the default cell in the GridView. I did it this way to (a) ensure that the cell I'm trying to select is non-null, and (b) I wondered if the getView method was resetting the selection somehow.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    // * Other code that sets up the view

    if (listener!=null) {
        if ((list.size()-1)==position) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Today position set: " + todayPosition);
            listener.todayPositionFound(todayPosition);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "LISTENER IS NULL");
    }

    return row;
}
```

and then...

```
public void todayPositionFound(final int position) {
    // * ------------------------
    // * On startup, select today
    // * ------------------------
    mCurrentlySelectedDate = DateHelper.todayAsString();
    Log.d(TAG, "Todays Position Found: " + position);
    View v = calendarView.getChildAt(position);
    if (v!=null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "V not NULL - SELECTING");
        v.setSelected(true);
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "SELECTED? " + calendarView.getSelectedItemPosition());
}
```

All of this goes off without a problem, aside from the fact that the view is then NOT selected. Furthermore, when I getSelectedItemPosition it returns -1 ... even though I just 'selected' position 16. Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Further information: If I take the view returned by the todayPositionFound method and findViewById and get the TextView within that view I can successfully select that TextView, including UI changes due to the selection. But this is not what I want... so I'm not totally sure what I'm doing wrong to select the containing view and not it's child TextView...

Comment: I've also found that if I select a cell in the GridView via onClick it works just fine. My guess here is that something is resetting the selection... I could be wrong, but at this point it is my best assumption.

Comment: OK, my guess is correct. If I delay the selection by 5 seconds it occurs as expected... something occurring at the initial app startup is clearing the selection.

Answer (score 1):

To get this working I used a Handler and Runnable:

```
    public void todayPositionFound(final int position) {
        Handler h = new Handler();
        Runnable r =new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                View v = calendarView.getChildAt(position);
                if (v!=null) {
                    v.setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        };
        h.postDelayed(r, 500);
   }
```

If someone has a better solution please do let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can only update the list scroll position after the the List/GridView has been drawn. This happens a short time after `onCreate()` or `onResume()` or `onCreateView()` has been called.

You could try using a Global layout listener to tell you when the GridView has been drawn, for example:

```
GridView calendarView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID);
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = calendarView.getViewTreeObserver(); 
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        this.calendarView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        View v = calendarView.getChildAt(position);

        if (v!=null) {
            v.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
});
```